# ios Who invoked that segue?

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

Recently started developing for IOS from Windows...

Using the latest version of XCode and storyboards. Is is possible to (programatically) see who (or what) invoked a segue?

As you can probably tell I'm not 100% with segues and how they work but I think I have a very basic understanding. So as to fill in those that want to know more; I have basically two scenes (I think that's what you call them in storyboard) and one has a push segue to another which is all started by a button. But I am looking at expanding the app so that 2 different scenes push via 2 different seques to another scene - but for the final scene I want it to know which was the previous scene that the user came from.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `UIViewController` method called `prepareForSegue:sender:`. `sender` is:

> The object that initiated the segue. You might use this parameter to
>   perform different actions based on which control (or other object)
>   initiated the segue.

As far as your question:

> but for the final scene I want it to know which was the previous scene that the user came from.

This can be done via tapping into the underlying `UINavigationController` (if used) or via `UIViewController`'s `parentViewController` method. There are a few other ways, but these are very broad answers since the question is non-specific in your implementation/setup.